# Jscrollpane : Changing the padding of the container

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have litteraly tortured this very usefull JS script in all ways, but the one thing that disappointed me, it's it unfriendly with CSS, and I can't do everything I want without using images to custom the drag button or the container.

I've checked the script, and I don't see any way to change only the padding of the top or bottom for a vertical scrollbar, or the left or right padding for a horizontal scrollbar.

I would like to use a "transform:skewY();" in CSS to give a futuristic style to the drag button, and its tips disapeared "under" the container (overflow: hidden, applying by the script, not the CSS).

My question is very simple : is there anyway to custom the paddings separately ?

Thank you for your answers !